# What is this extender?

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently got an Arduino starter kit from a friend that he wasn't using and this came with it but, i can't find anything about it, cause i don't know how to search for it. 
Anyone can enlighten me what it is?

[image]

Comment: Looks similar to:
"8 Channel 5V/3.3V IIC UART SPI TTL Logic Level Converter"
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32977711795.html

Comment: @FilipFranik Thanks that is the correct one

Comment: @FilipFranik you should post that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to:

"8 Channel 5V/3.3V IIC UART SPI TTL Logic Level Converter"

[image: 8 Channel 5V/3.3V IIC UART SPI TTL Logic Level Converter]

Image above was screen capped from: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32977711795.html